# How do I reference a control array outside the sub that created it?

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program that creates forms at runtime using this code,

```
Dim a As Integer = Screen.AllScreens.Length
Dim frm2(a) As Form
For b As Integer = 0 To a - 1
    frm2(b) = new form
    ' ...  set attributes to the form here
    frm2(b).Show()
Next
```

My questions is how can I later from another sub access these forms?  For instance if I wanted to draw graphics on these forms how would I access them? They're not available outside the subroutine that created them and you can't make a public array of controls in vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare the `frm2` array outside of your `Sub` method, at the class-level.  For future reference, variables declared at the class-level are called *fields*.  Fields are scoped to the class, so any method in the class can access them.  For instance:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private frm2() As Form

    Public Sub CreateForms()
        Dim a As Integer = Screen.AllScreens.Length
        ReDim frm2(a)
        For b As Integer = 0 To a - 1
            frm2(b) = New Form()
            ' ...  set attributes to the form here
            frm2(b).Show()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

For what it's worth, I would recommend using a `List(Of Form)` rather than an array.  That way you don't have to worry about re-sizing it, for instance:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private forms As New List(Of Form)()

    Public Sub CreateForms()
        For i As Integer = 0 To Screen.AllScreens.Length - 1
            Dim frm2 As New Form()
            ' ...  set attributes to the form here
            frm2.Show()
            forms.Add(frm2)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. Think I was having a temporary brain fart because I thought of the same thing last night. I was thinking for some reason I had tried it and it had failed but apparently I hadn't. Thanks for the help.  -Chris

Answer (score 0):

Rather than defining the forms in the sub itself, if you create them as form variables. Then you can access these from any sub within that form.

You should then be able to create whatever you need on the form, or preferably create a Public Sub on the form which can be called from elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have an example?  I can't define a variable to each form because I don't know how many forms I'm going to need. it would depend on how many screens the computer has.